# django-tenant-schemas: How to drop a schema within utils.py?

Tags: django

tenant-schemas, and I am wondering how should I delete a schema from my database? Basically I have a trial system on my program, and once the trial duration is up, I would like to delete the schema entirely. Is there any way for me to do so? Either using django-tenant-schemas or using connection.cursor? I would like to achieve this inside my utils.py

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM public.tenant_client WHERE id = '%s'", [current_tenant.id])
connection.commit()
```

this might help